# Why is $\sqrt {x^2}=|x|$ ? Inverse functions confusion.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The inverse function theorem says for all $x$ in the domain of $f$, $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$. Let $f$ be $x^2$. Thus $\sqrt{x^2}=x$. Why is this wrong?

Comment: This website is for questions of math research. Your question will probably be migrated to a more suitable site shortly.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I've just rolled this back

Comment: This is not the Inverse Function Theorem.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Surely the OP doesn't mean **the** inverse function theorem.

Comment: I'm sure they don't. What I meant is that what they have called the Inverse Function Theorem is not actually the Inverse Function Theorem.

Comment: I can't make any sense of the first sentence in the title. Could you clarify it?

Comment: @RickDecker By definition, if $f:A\to B$ and $f^{-1}:B\to A$ are inverses, $f\circ f^{-1}={\rm id}_B$ and $f^{-1}\circ f={\rm id}_A$.

Answer (score 3):

I think maybe there is some confusion about inversion.  If you have a function f which does something to x, then the inverse function f<sup>-1</sup> undoes whatever f does.    That's  clear enough if f(x) = x + 1.  To undo the sum, you have to subtract.  But when f(x) is x<sup>2</sup> the question of an inverse gets tricky.  Is the inverse of 9 going to 3 or is it going to be -3.  Without further information we don't know.

The trouble is that x<sup>2</sup> mapped two different numbers into 9, so you can't know how to undo it. Any function which has a clearly defined inverse must map each x in its domain to a unique y in its range.  x<sup>2</sup> doesn't do that.

In order to make an inverse possible, we have to pick a domain for x which makes it a 1-1 mapping into its range.  In the case of f(x) =  x<sup>2</sup> we usually pick the domain x ≥ 0.  Then when we are trying to turn the process around, it is clear that f<sup>-1</sup>(9) is 3, not -3, because -3 was never under consideration.

Yes, of course we could have used the domain x ≤ 0; then f<sup>-1</sup>(9) = -3.

So when someone is asking you for an inverse, you want to make sure you know what the original domain was.  The fact that a square root sign was involved does not change the situation.  The answer can't be "x" because we don't know what x is unless the original domain was clearly defined.

As a side note, I've found that students really wish domain and range would go away and leave them alone.  But if no one discusses them, computations can get mixed up in a lot of ways, not just with inverses.  So taking the trouble to understand and pay attention to domains and ranges it worth it.

Answer (score 2):

$f:[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R\;/ \;\;x\mapsto x^2$ is invertible, and the theorem works when $x\geqslant 0$ just fine, and gives $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=x$ since $x\geqslant 0$. The function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\;\;/\;\;x\mapsto x^2$ is **not** invertible over the whole real line, only over the positive or negative semi-axes, so the theorem doesn't apply at all. In particular, the symbol $\sqrt x$ is reserved exclusively for the unique non-negative real $y$ such that $y^2=x  -$ that is, by definition, $(\sqrt x)^2=x$. If $x$ is negative, $x^2$ is positive, so $\sqrt{x^2}$ is positive by *definition*. What is the unique positive real number such that $y^2=x^2$? It is $-x$. This is $|x|$. In any case $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is $f(x) = x^2$ with domain $\mathbb{R}$ is not invertible. This is because for all $f(x) = n \neq 0$, we could either have $x = \sqrt{n}$ or $x = -\sqrt{n}$ but only one value is allowed for the inverse to be a function. To avoid this problem we can consider the function $g(x) = x^2$ with domain $x \geq 0$. Then $g$ it *is* invertible and the inverse is $\sqrt{x}$.

So what you stated is right but you have to examine two halves ($x \geq 0$ and $x \leq 0$) of $x^2$.

For $x \geq 0$, we have $g(x) = x^2$, so $g^{-1}(g(x)) = x \implies \sqrt{x^2} = x$.

For $x \leq 0$, we have $g(-x) = (-x)^2 = x^2$ (remember the domain of $g$ is all numbers $\geq 0$) and so $g^{-1}(g(-x)) = -x \implies \sqrt{(-x)^2} = -x \implies \sqrt{x^2} = -x$. Putting these two together, we have
$$
\sqrt{x^2} =
\begin{cases}
x & x \geq 0\\
-x & x \leq 0
\end{cases}
$$
But the right side is the definition of $|x|$ and that's why $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.